# CustomDialog - prevent multiple click

Tags: android

Is it possible to use a flag (in the same way as the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`) to prevent displaying of a `CustomDialog` when we click more than once on a button ?

I don't want to use a `boolean` value each time i create a new `Dialog`...

Comment: Disable the button after clicking?

Comment: this solution does not seem very ergonomic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i used a boolean. If someone have an other idea...

Comment: You can use this project: https://github.com/fengdai/clickguard to resolve this problem with a single statement:

    ClickGuard.guard(button);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a `CustomDialog` class, so I assume you mean a "custom `Dialog`" (probably an `AlertDialog`?).

If that's the case then no, there is no built in way to tell it to automatically prevent subsequent `Dialog`s from being presented.

We ran into this issue within our own application, and ended up writing our own extension to the `Activity` class.  It has a method to present a dialog, which makes certain only one dialog is being shown.  All of our Activities extend from this class, so we can use this method universally instead of `showDialog()`.

If you are targeting Android 3.0 or later ([haha, yeah right...](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)), then I would suggest you take a look at [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)s instead, which are the new mechanism for this.